# How is google drive opening files?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-drive-api

I am having a problem with Google Drive opening new blank tabs when trying to open fresh files, for example csv or xlsx. After opening the tab, there is a conversion taking place with a new file being generated and a link to it opened in the new tab. So far I believe that this is happening by some type of communication between the tabs, the old one sending information to the new one more precisely.

I need to intercept the URL to the file, so that I can pass it to a tab when this is happening in a Third party Chromium based application. I honestly didn't expect it to be this roundabout and complicated to handle Google, as it is the first time I am encountering such an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Natively those kind of files cannot be opened in Drive, so what you are saying is true. First a copy of the file is created in the corresponding native mime type, in the case of a csv or xlsx, the corresponding file would be a Spreadsheet.

After the file is created, the url of the new file is opened in a new tab.

If your application is integrated with Drive, the user would have to open the file using the option "open with" and then select your app. In this scenario there is no necessity to intercept the URL to open the file with your app.

Also, while configuring your integration with Drive, you can select the extensions and mime types that your application can handle, so when the user opens a file, by default it would be opened with your app.
Check this documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/integrate-open

Comment: The application in question is not integrated with Drive, but a browser. That is the reason I am looking for some type of generic way to get what I need. If possible we would like to avoid adding Drive specific code, as Google are using the same browser technology as the rest of us.

Comment: What do you mean with "generic way to get what i need"? you want to use Drive services without using Drive API? Have you tried anything so far? what errors do you get? is there some code you can share? .. check this documentation on how to ask questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: By "generic way" I mean to use HTML/JS to find how the blank tab is sending requests and opening an URL.
I want to use Google Drive like I would use any other site, but since it does something unusual, I would like to investigate it.
I have tried to intercept every single request sent from the pages. What I noticed as a difference is that there is never https://docs.google.com/a/company/spreadsheets/d/fileID/edit?usp=drive_web sent in the new tab. Since the file that is being opened in Drive needs to be converted, the information about it is being sent to the other browser tab after opening.